# Codec not found for requested operation: ['org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SimpleDateType' <-> com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate]

Tags: cassandra, java-8, entities

I am using java8 and cassandra in my application.
The datatype of current_date in cassandra table is 'date'.
I am using entities to map to the table values. and the datatype in entity for the same field is com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.

When I am trying to retrieve a record 
`'Select * from table where current_date='2017-06-06';'` 
I am getting the following error'

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec 
not found for requested operation: 
['org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.SimpleDateType' <-> 
com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate]

Comment: this? http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/extras/

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar error message while querying cassandra from Presto.

I needed to set to `cassandra.protocol-version=V4` in cassandra.properties in Presto to resolve the problem in my case.

If you get this problem while using a java SDK application, check whether changing protocol version resolves the problem. In some cases, you have to write your own codec implementation.

Comment: what relation presto has to this question?

Answer (score -1):

By default, Java driver will map date type into `com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate Java type.`

If you need to convert date to java.time.LocalDate, then you need to add extras to your project :
You can specify codec for given column only:

```
 @Column(codec = LocalDateCodec.class) java.time.LocalDate current_date ;
```

If these two didnot work, please have a look into the code how you are creating the session,cluster etc to connect to database. Since date is a new addition to cassandra data type, Protocol version can also have an impact. 
Update the version accordingly

Comment: I faced the similar issue. i fixed it by updating the version to 4 from 3